# Why is splice function giving me a singular output versus an array

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var index = arr.indexOf(2);

arr = arr.splice(index, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

In theory it should index 2, so value of index should be 1. Then it should delete 1 item at that index and leave me with arr = [1,3,4] but it is giving me arr = [2].

Comment: `splice` changes the content of the array itself and returns an array of deleted values like so `let arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`. 
Check out the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

`arr.splice` doesn't return the spliced array instead it returns the removed/deleted elements as an array. It also doesn't create a new array, it modifies the actual array so you don't have to reassign.

You can just use:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var index = arr.indexOf(2);
arr.splice(index, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr.splice(index, 1);` means to alter **arr** itself, and returns the value(s) that arr has been removed.

Hence `arr=arr.splice(index,1)` makes arr became the value arr removed at the right hand side.